# If $v_{contact,road}$ in rolling motion is zero, how the contact point still manages to move forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

If velocity of contact point of a rigid body performing rolling motion w.r.t road is zero then how the point gets delocalised from its initial position after some time?

My textbook says, **At any instant a rolling sphere may be considered to be in pure rotation about an axis through the point of contact.This axis translates forward with the speed equal to the speed of its centre**.

The above statement makes me more confused as my same textbook says that $v_{contact,road}$ is zero and simultaneously it says that the axis passing through the contact point translates forward.

**EDIT**

My question is somewhat different from [Rolling as pure rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159920/) as I also want to know that how the axis passing through the point of contact translates forward if the 
$v_{contact,road}$ is zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling as pure rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159920/)

Comment: Re: The edit - The linked duplicate seems to ask about that, and the top answer spends quite a bit of space discussing that point of contact P and how it moves.

Answer (score 0):

Axis of rotation is just a mental construct in space. When rolling without slipping, it always passes through the point of contact of body with the surface.

This axis moving does not mean that the mass point of the body that is in contact with the surface moves the same way. The mass point in contact is at rest momentarily, and will move up away from the surface when the axis moves forward. As the axis moves, different mass points assume its position, coming from above towards the surface, stopping momentarily and then move back upwards.